# Configure Pop Up Layout

Tags: page-layout, mousehover

A noobish question.

Can someone tell me where to configure this layout which pops up when hovering over ?

[image]

I searched under "Users" and I can see a layout called "Compact Layout" but looks like that will be available only for Salesforce1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Standard Objects:** Click on Setup | Customize | (Object you wish to edit) | Page Layout

**For Custom Objects:** Click on Setup | Create | Objects | (Object you wish to edit) | Page Layout

Near the top right of the page there will be a link labeled **Mini Page Layout**

[How do I change the fields used by Hover Details?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-do-I-change-the-fields-used-by-Hover-Details-1327109127166&language=en_US)